# Obtain a variable based matrix starting from a observation one

Tags: r, matrix, distance

I have some trouble trasforming a matrix in R.
Suppose that you have a dataset with n observations and k categorical variables (I haven't observed this dataset).
I was given the distance matrix containing the distance between each pair of observations, therefore I have a matrix n x n.

I would like to transform this matrix into a matrix whose dimensions are the cross product of the categories of my categorical variables.

Example

```
library(cluster)
a = factor(c(rep("c", 3), rep("d", 3), rep("e", 3)))
b = factor(c(rep(c("f","g","h"), times=3)))
y = c(3,1,1,1,5,1,1,1,4)
dati = data.frame(a, b, y)
k = ncol(dati) - 1
var = dati[, -length(dati)]
dist = daisy(var, metric = "gower") # Matrix that I want to obtain


t0 = as.matrix(xtabs(y~a+b))
n = sum(t0)
long = as.data.frame.table(t0)
longer = as.data.frame(long[rep(1:nrow(long), long$Freq), -3], row.names = seq(n))
dist2 = daisy(longer, metric = "gower") # This is the matrix I am given in order to obtain matrix dist.
```

Suppose that I don't have my data, but I only have the matrix dist2. How can I obtain the matrix dist?
The two matrices provide the same information, just one is a transformation of the other.
In particular in dist2[1,1] = dist[1,2] = dist[1,3] = 0 since the first three observations are equal. Therefore in matrix dist I should have entry = 0 in correspondence of the diagonal cell that has as row name (c,f) and column name (c,f).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I try to run your code, there is first an error because you define `cross_prod` but then use `cros_prod` with only one `s` in the next line. If I fix this typo then your loop errors because `k` is not defined. Other than a "k x k" matrix I do not understand what your goal is.

Comment: Also I don't see an `n x n` matrix. `dati` is not square. Is `dati` what you are referring to as the distance matrix, or is that something else?

Comment: And is it deliberate that `a` is a `factor` and `b` is a `character`? That seems strange.

Comment: Since my guess is wrong, please edit the question to include the expected output for your sample input.

Comment: Okay, will you post the code to create the input you want to start with??

Comment: Done, is it more understandable now?

Comment: In your description of the nxn matrix later called `dist2` you say that the entries of `dist2` are counts. But `dist2` has many entries that are 0.5 - if it is supposed to be counts I would expect only integer values. So that is confusing.

Comment: Conceptually, I still don't quite get it... it seems like `dist` and `dist2` are different summaries of more detailed data, and it is not clear to me that `dist` can be calculated from `dist2` directly without knowing `dati` or `long` or `longer`. Could you give an example calculation? For example `dist[5, 2]` is `0.5`.  What numbers from `dist2` can be used to calculate that `0.5`.?

Comment: The two matrices provide the same information. I just need to be able to transform the n x n matrix (dist2) into dist where dist is a matrix that as row and column name has the pairs [(c,f); (c,g); (c, h); (d,f); (d,g)...]

Comment: That's confusing because the `dist` matrix in your question which you say is your goal doesn't have those column names... it has different dimensions which makes it seem like there are more differences than the column and row names.